# Why doesn't textFieldShouldReturn automatically resigns and returns true?

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I am new to iOS development and am reading the swift tutorial from apple.
It seems to me that the code below is always needed so that when a user hits return in a text field, it resigns the first responder.

```
  func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
  }
```

I understand that swift provides the flexibility for programmers to control this behavior, but in what scenarios of a real app do I not need these two lines? It seems to me that I always need them so why doesn't swift automatically do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be very wrong for Cocoa to *assume* that tapping Return should *automatically* dismiss the keyboard. It is rightly left up to you. The user's expectation is probably that this will dismiss the keyboard. And you, too, probably would rather not have the keyboard hanging around forever. Well, `resignFirstResponder` dismisses the keyboard. Still, suppose there is something wrong with the text. When the user taps Return, you might check the text and *not* dismiss the keyboard. You might put up an alert instead, warning that there's a problem. You wouldn't want to be overridden by some automatic behavior of the framework!

By the way, there are other ways to cause tapping Return to dismiss the keyboard other than implementing this method. In apps that use those other ways, this method might not appear at all.

Comment: What other ways are you referring to?

Comment: For example, the Did End on Exit control event.

Comment: Thanks! That's the answer I want. If I may ask another question, when do I need UIImagePickerControllerDelegate but not UINavigationControllerDelegate? It seems to me that I always need both of them

Comment: Do not leech. If you have another question, ask another question. If my answer to this question is right, please accept it. Do not try to hold your answerer hostage with additional unrelated comments.

Answer (score -1):

That's a default.

However, if you prefer the "automatic enable return", you can now in Swift 2.0.

You still need to make your class conform to UITextFieldDelegate, and you still need to configure the delegate in Interface Builder.

Make a protocol extension:

```
extension UITextFieldDelegate {
  func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
     NSLog("default behavior")
     textField.resignFirstResponder()
     return true
  }
}
```

No, that's the default behavior for all your App...

You can still override the method in class.